# Why does dividing "population" by "average life expectancy" generate the "death rate"?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I've a general basic question: why when we divide a population to the average life expectancy (average lifetime) creates the number of people who die at time t?

I think this is related to the Little's law. but I can't really grasp why when we divide the number of people to its average lifetime creates the number of people who died.

Can anyone explain in simple terms. I really appreciate your response.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I will give it a try: If life expectancy is given to be, say $74$; We then expect this person to live for $74$ years, and then dies (forgive my sub-human interpretation). But this can also be seen slightly different: Each year, $1/74$th part of this person dies, until after $74$ years, he's truly gone. So when you have a population of $74$ people, $1/74$th of EACH person dies, which is in total $74$ times $1/74$ which is $1$ person dies. Here you have a very basic example that essentially states" population divided by life expectancy = number of people die.

Answer (score 0):

Your affirmation is mathematically false.

Suppose you have 1000 persons with a life expectancy of exactly 100 years.

Now suppose 999 persons are 50 years old and 1 is 100 year old and dies.

You have 1000/100 = 10 and 10 ≠ 1  QED

Now usually life expectancy is approximated by the average age of death observed on the current year.

Which is E = ∑ ni Ai /∑ni , ni being the number of people dying at age Ai

Now N being the total population, N/E = ∑ni . N/ ∑ ni Ai

Your statement is equivalent to N/ ∑ ni Ai = 1 or ∑ ni Ai = N, which as seen, is false

However, if you take a stable population (N is a constant) with a stable distribution of dying age and number of birth, that you observe for J years, you have *on average*  ∑ nij Aij = J.n . E = J.N, which brings to your affirmation. (I am to lazy to write the detail of the proof)

So in summary, it is true on average if you have some stability hypothesis on the population, which are in real life more or less respected.